# How to correctly format a c# 7-zip string with a password?

Tags: c#, 7zip

So I am coding an encryption application in C#, which calls on 7zip to encrypt a folder into a 7zip archive with a previous entered password. The trouble is, for some reason it's seeing the file I am trying to compress into the 7zip archive as a 7zip file itself, when it actually is just a normal folder so not sure why that's happening. Here is the code:

```
string sourceName = @"c:\putfilesforencryptionhere";
string targetName = @"c:\encryptedfileshere.7z";
string password = Form2.verify;

// Initialize process information.
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zG.exe";

// Use 7-zip
// specify a=archive and -tgzip=gzip
// and then target file in quotes followed by source file in quotes
p.Arguments = "a \"" + targetName + " -p" + password + " " + sourceName;
```

And when running the program, 7zip returns this error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. cannot open file c:\encryptedfileshere.7z  -p09/28/2020 11:17:29 AM c:\putfilesforencryptionhere.7z.

`String password = Form2.verify` as it is a password that is entered in a previous form. I wonder why 7-zip would see c:\putfilesforencryptionhere as a 7zip file when it is a normal folder?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

When setting the value of `p.Arguments`, there is an escaped quote `\"` before `targetName` but not after. Therefore, the entirety of the following string is being interpreted as the archive name (as seen in the error message).

Try

```
p.Arguments = "a \"" + targetName + "\" -p" + password + " " + sourceName;
```

Or use `ArgumentList` to avoid escaping issues.

```
p.ArgumentList.Add("a");
p.ArgumentList.Add(targetName);
p.ArgumentList.Add("-p" + password);
p.ArgumentList.Add(sourceName);
```

Comment: Good catch, I read it three times and missed that!
I also think it would be easier to avoid errors with concatenation like this by using string interpolation i.e. `p.Arguments = @$"a \{targetName}\ -p{password} {sourceName}`

Comment: With your first suggestion, it creates the archive, but then does not add the password. I wonder why that might be, thank you.

Comment: There could be an escaping issue if the password has a space in it. In the error message it looks like the password is `09/28/2020 11:17:29 AM`. I recommend using `ArgumentList` to avoid escaping issues.